# Android How to Display Arrow line between to Two Images in Programatically?

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

does anyone have an idea for how to display the Arrow line between two lines with out user Interaction?

[image]

Here I put two `ImageView`s in XML file (Image1 and Image 2) in this Views implemented `onTouchlistener()`. when i drag images one place to another Place Depending on that Distance That arrow line Also Increase and Decrease. How to solve this issue Any one have idea of this help me Thank you.....

`EDIT :` How to find out the difference between that two Views.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us some code? One way to do it would be to override the onDraw method the parent view and draw on the canvas.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      canvas.drawLine(startx, starty, stopx, stopy, paint);
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLine%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29